# Strapi Meilisearch 405 when trying to add content-type to index

Tags: strapi, meilisearch

so I just installed meilisearch and the corresponding strapi plugin for it. As I'm using this instance strictly for development purposes and to facilitate development, I'm running meilisearch without encryption via the `--env development` flag.

So my server is running, and I've installed the strapi plugin, in the settings tab of the plugin I've set the host to `127.0.0.1` and left the api key field empty (not needing it because of running the search server with the `--dev` - flag).

When going to the "collection" tab though and trying to index a collection I'm getting an exception `Warning: Method not allowed` in the backend of my strapi app.

The console which runs strapi is showing the following:

```
[2023-06-26 11:36:49.587] error: meilisearch: Method Not Allowed
[2023-06-26 11:36:49.587] http: POST /meilisearch/content-type (36 ms) 200
```

My first guess was that maybe the route wasn't allowed for the current user which is also the default behaviour for any content-type bound route, which has to be allowed in the users-permissions plugin. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find anything related to this in the settings of my roles.

Is there something I'm missing?
What can I do to be allowed indexing my models?

I'm on strapi v 4.7.0 using Meilisearch v1.2 and the strapi-plugin-meilisearch v.0.9.1.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers,
derelektrischemoench

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this out by myself. Turns out you have to set the correct port in strapi-meilisearch settings in the strapi backend. The correct port being the one meilisearch outputs when starting the server.